# WebApi 2 -cant determined DataProtection.IDataProtector Dependency Injection with structuremap

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, structuremap

I'm using [this beriliant](https://github.com/VahidN/AspNetIdentityDependencyInjectionSample) project for base of my MVC project.
But when I use WebAPI for project there is problem in `IDataProtector` injection.
I redesign base and upload [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzwMa6bE1ZA0OUZCSUpPYjg1S2M/view?usp=sharing), and add a console project for testing authorizing with WebAPI.

This is structuremap initialization :

```
            private static readonly Lazy<Container> _containerBuilder =
        new Lazy<Container>(initStructureMap, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

    public static IContainer Container
    {
        get { return _containerBuilder.Value; }
    }
return new Container(ioc =>
        {
            ioc.For<IUnitOfWork>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use(() => new DbContext());

            ioc.For<IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>>().Use<TicketSerializer>();
            ioc.For<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>().Use<SecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>();

        });
```

and in WebApiConfig class DI is like this:

```
            var container = StructuremapMvc.Container;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(
            typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new  StructureMapHttpControllerActivator(container));
```

in my startup I create dataprotector with IAppBuilder :

```
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        StructuremapMvc.Container.Configure(config =>
        {
            config.For<IDataProtectionProvider>()
                  .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
                  .Use(() => app.GetDataProtectionProvider());
        });
     }
```

It start after WebApiConfig and IDataProtection not work in WebApi. my ServiceLayer is in separate project and DataProtection need to inject there.

Comment: Please show a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) *here* instead of linking to large pieces of code elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need add two class to your project :

**1-StructureMapDependencyScope Class**

```
using StructureMap;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http.Dependencies;

namespace Project.Helpers
{
    public class StructureMapDependencyScope : IDependencyScope
    {
        protected readonly IContainer Container;

        public StructureMapDependencyScope(IContainer container)
        {
            if (container == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
            }

            this.Container = container;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Container.Dispose();
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            if (serviceType == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            try
            {
                return serviceType.IsAbstract || serviceType.IsInterface
                           ? this.Container.TryGetInstance(serviceType)
                           : this.Container.GetInstance(serviceType);
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return this.Container.GetAllInstances(serviceType).Cast<object>();
        }
    }
}
```

**2-StructureMapDependencyResolver Class**

```
using StructureMap;
using System.Web.Http.Dependencies;

namespace Project.Helpers
{
    public class StructureMapDependencyResolver : StructureMapDependencyScope, IDependencyResolver
    {
        public StructureMapDependencyResolver(IContainer container)
            : base(container)
        {
        }
        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            IContainer child = this.Container.GetNestedContainer();
            return new StructureMapDependencyResolver(child);
        }
    }
}
```

at the end replace this code with yours in **WebApiConfig Class**:

```
// IoC Config
var container = SmObjectFactory.Container;

// Web API configuration and services
config.DependencyResolver = new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container);
```

read more about Dependency Injection in ASP.NET MVC 4 and Web API by StructureMap [here](http://skydevelop.ir/share/2235/%D8%AA%D8%B2%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%82-%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%B3%D8%AA%DA%AF%DB%8C-%D9%87%D8%A7-%D8%AF%D8%B1-web-api-%D9%88-asp-net-mvc).

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly register implementation of `IDataProtector` in the container.

Sample configuration might looks like this:

```
ioc.For<IDataProtector>().Use(() => new DpapiDataProtectionProvider().Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
ioc.For<ITextEncoder>().Use<Base64UrlTextEncoder>();
```

Bear in mind that this specific configuration might not suit your exact needs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: when i use this, OwinContext.GetUserManager<>() return null! seems like this [link](http://bit.ly/1FOPIZO)

Comment: On my machine userManager is resolved without problems. I have only issue with not existing user.

Comment: appreciate if u have time to fix [this](http://bit.ly/1A0SVPq) template. it has a console project for test. in my project don't work. maybe u are using different way and i can't explain currect on first post. thanks ...

Comment: @Princedotnet, I've just added these 2 registrations included in my answer.